# Drawing markers on a google map starting from a php array

Tags: php, html, google-maps-api-3

All right, I'll try to explain my problem as clearly as I can. I already tried a lot of possible solution but never happen to find the right one.
I also want to say this is a tutorial for me, i am just a beginner in combining JS, PHP and GMAPv3 APIs.
I hope that someone can help me in solving this.
That being said, here is my code with a few lines to explain what i want to do.

**The problem involves 3 main files.**

**1) process.php (this file generates an array of coordinates)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>MyTest</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/content.css" />
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/gmapinit.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    ...after some lines of code i build this...
    $myarray = ...;
    ...and here i move to the second file
    echo "<input type=\"button\" value=\"Next!\" onClick=\"location.href='map.html'\">";
    ?>
</body>
```

**2) map.html (this file is responsible for drawing the map on the screen)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>MyTest</title>
    <link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="css/googlemap.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCbNM4y2fJ4AdCoXcWW-sGXPl5nXaJogPA&sensor=false">
    </script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/gmapinit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
</head>
<body onLoad="init_map_and_markers()">
    <div id="map_canvas">
    </div>       
</body>
```

**2) gmapinit.js (the javascript file that builds the map and "should" get the array as parameter to draw markers accordingly)**

```
function init_map_and_markers() {
var global_markers = [];

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({});
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(27.059126, -41.044922);
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
    myOptions);

//Of course here myarray is not defined but the point is making it available here so i can loop through it and place my markers!

for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
    for(var count = myarray.length - 1; count >= 0; --count) { 
        var o = myarray[count];
        var lat = parseFloat(o.lat);
        var lng = parseFloat(o.lng);
        var markerdata = o.user;

        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        var contentString = "<html><body><div><p><h2>" + markerdata + "</h2></p></div></body></html>";

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: "Coordinates: " + lat + " , " + lng + " | Marker Data: " + markerdata
        });

        marker['infowindow'] = contentString;

        global_markers[i] = marker;

        google.maps.event.addListener(global_markers[i], 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(this['infowindow']);
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });
    }    
}
```

}

**So the main question is, how can i pass $myarray from process.php to map.html making it available to gmapinit.js???**

I am asking this avoiding to write down all code-tests i did because maybe my all thinking is wrong...that's why i am writing down the most "clean" code i got.

Code possible solutions would be much appreciated, and don't hesitate to ask for details if i missed something.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may use the markers as argument for init_map_and_markers()

```
<body onLoad="init_map_and_markers(<?php echo json_encode($phpArrayMarkersDefinition); ?>)">
```

..then you may access this array inside the function:

```
function init_map_and_markers(markers) 
{
  //....
  for(var i=0;i<markers.length;++i)
  {
    //create the markers here
  }

  //....
}
```

Comment: Yes! That is actually one of the possible solutions i implemented. But the problem is that the array is not available on map.html, only in process.php. what would be the best practice to pass it considering that the array is the result of a searching command, thus dynamic.

Comment: You may use a hidden form-field and post the result to map.html , then you'll be able to access the results in map.html.

Comment: Can you provide an example for my case? I dont know how to do it especially because the js function is called right at the start of the body preventing me to write any kind of codeto retrieve variables in map.html. thanks for the help. And also, is that the best way to do it? Seems quite unsecure to me.

Comment: Well, it's insecure indeed. To make it secure you may store the data inside a session. In that case you can leave your code as it is, and in map.html retrieve the data from the session(of course map.html has to be parsed by PHP in that case to make the Session available). The usage would be the same as posted in my answer, $phpArrayMarkersDefinition has to be the session-variable containing the data

Comment: I also tried to use session to be honest, just to know if the steps are correct, i have to use session_start() in process.php, then store $myarray in $_SESSION['myarray'] and then retrieve it from map.html? but where? I can't do it in the body, the function is called before i can code anything in there...is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Where you need it, replace `$phpArrayMarkersDefinition` in my answer with `$_SESSION['myarray']` . But you must be sure that PHP will parse the map.html(by default PHP did not parse *.html-files) and start the session also in map.html

Comment: Thanks again Dr.Molle, I'll give it a shot and see if everything works. :)

Comment: i did a few test and the session itself is working very well, the problem is that i can't start the session in map.html file because i can't write php code inside the body before the function gets called. Now probably i should move that _init_map_and_markers_ code and put it a bit further down...but that's something related to Google map API i guess

Comment: Confirmed working, i just started the session in the body and then called the `init_map_and_markers` function with a separate js script.